# Sending data to Shiny server and back happens with delay

Tags: r, shiny

I am expecting that by pressing the square div/button (3rd element on the page) a random number will appear under the element and the color of the element will also change. Unfortunately it seems that I have to press the button on the top of the page in order for this to happen and I can't figure out why?

my **index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/shiny.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Press me!" class="action-button">
        <p><div id="text" class="shiny-text-output" style="width: 150px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
        <p><div id="mydiv" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
        <pre id="results" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // send data to shiny server
        document.getElementById ("mydiv").onclick = function() {
            var number = Math.random();
            Shiny.onInputChange ("mydata", number);
        };

        // handlers to receive data from server
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ("myColorHandler",
            function (color) {
                document.getElementById ("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```

my **server.R**

```
shinyServer (function (input, output, session)
{
    observe ({
        x = input$button;

        output$text = renderText ({
            if (! is.null (x))
            {
                if (x %% 2 == 0) { paste (x, ": you are even", sep=""); }
                else { paste (x, ": you are odd", sep=""); }
            }
        })
    });

    output$results = renderPrint ({
        input$mydata;
    })

    observe ({
        input$mydata;
        color = rgb (runif (1), runif (1), runif (1));
        session$sendCustomMessage (type="myColorHandler", color);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` on your button. Currently your button is acting as a `submitButton` rather then an `actionButton`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/shiny.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="button" type="button" name="submit" value="Press me!" class="action-button">
        <p><div id="text" class="shiny-text-output" style="width: 150px; height: 25px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
        <p><div id="mydiv" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
        <pre id="results" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // send data to shiny server
        document.getElementById ("mydiv").onclick = function() {
            var number = Math.random();
            Shiny.onInputChange ("mydata", number);
        };

        // handlers to receive data from server
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ("myColorHandler",
            function (color) {
                document.getElementById ("mydiv").style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```