# Button press twice?

Tags: r, shiny

In my **server.R** I have

```
library (shiny)

shinyServer (function (input, output, session)
{
    values <- reactiveValues()      # create a reactiveValues object, to let us use settable reactive values
    values$lastAction <- NULL       # to start out, lastAction == NULL, meaning nothing clicked yet

    # an observe block for each button, to record that the action happened
    observe ({
        if (input$runButton != 0) {
            values$lastAction <- 'run'
        }
    });

    observe ({

        # make sure we have data
        if (is.null (values$lastAction))
            return (NULL);

        print ("Detected button Press");
    });

})
```

and in my **index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Structural Variant (SV) Analysis</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="shared/shiny.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/> 
        <style>
            body { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <br>
        <form action="">
            <div><input id="runButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Press me!" class="button action-button"></div>
        </form>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is why do I need to press the button two times (at least) before I get the "Detected button Press"? How can I edit my code in order to have only a single button press?

Comment: Can't you use `<button ...></button>` instead? After the second click, further clicks also fail to alert the server.

Comment: same result. two button presses required.

Comment: Works for me..post your syntax?

Comment: Replace the `<input ...` with `<button id="runButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Press me!" class="button action-button"></button>`

Comment: try `<button id="runButton" type="button" class="btn action-button">Press me!</button>`

Comment: Dont use `submit` this declares a submit button rather then an action button under the shiny bindings as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539013/sending-data-to-shiny-server-and-back-happens-with-delay . Forms that include a submit button do not automatically update their outputs when inputs change, rather they wait until the user explicitly clicks the submit button hence the 2 clicks.

Comment: OK. It works. Thank you very much. As you can tell I am very new to shiny and R.